# Using XML file as android application data holder

Tags: java, android, xml, android-contentprovider

I have developed app which holds data in .xml file in res/xml/myfilename.xml and binds all the data to expandable list view.

XML structure:

```
<companyes>

<company>
<name> </name>
<employees>
<employee>
(employee parameters)
<employee>
</employees>
</company>

...

</companyes>
```

Now I am trying to implement data editing/deleting feature and I have found out that it seems to be impossible (using structure like this): you can not edit resources nor assets folder content on runtime. Is this true?

Is it possible to solve this problem by using structure like I use (XML for data holding)? Or should I use some other method? contentprovider? (Im new in android development and haven't got to the part where content provider is disgussed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct you can not modify the data inside of your application.  Your .apk is immutable.  You need to store this data in your persistent storage (in a database or a raw file) available through Context.

Answer (score 0):

My two cents: I experienced the same kind of issue some times ago (+ I have to share the underlying data between several applications). I finally used a ContentProvider with à SQLite database and manage xml to SQLite back and forth conversion on desktop.

I suggest to use a sqlite database.